# Can't import Looker API anymore

Tags: python, python-3.x, looker

When trying to

```
import looker_sdk
```

in my code, I get a lot of error messages, and can't use the API anymore...
I was able to use this 3 weeks ago, and haven't change my code at all.
I went on 2 weeks vacation and it didn't work anymore.

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Humilton\Desktop\Main\Tests\Looker_Download_Look_Receive_Dates.py", line 1, in <module>
    import looker_sdk
  File "C:\Users\Humilton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\looker_sdk\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from looker_sdk.sdk.api31 import methods, methods as methods31  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\Humilton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\looker_sdk\sdk\api31\methods.py", line 32, in <module>
    from . import models as mdls
  File "C:\Users\Humilton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\looker_sdk\sdk\api31\models.py", line 11935, in <module>
    sr.converter31.register_structure_hook(
  File "C:\Users\Humilton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\cattr\converters.py", line 186, in register_structure_hook
    self._structure_func.register_cls_list([(cl, func)])
  File "C:\Users\Humilton\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\cattr\multistrategy_dispatch.py", line 45, in register_cls_list
    self._single_dispatch.register(cls, handler)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\functools.py", line 856, in register
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Invalid first argument to `register()`. ForwardRef('AccessToken') is not a class.
[Finished in 1.4s]
```

It's a work laptop.
I've reinstalled Python (Python 3.10.2).
I've reinstalled the Looker SDK (using pip).

I'm trying to use the Looker SDK, so I can download data from the Looker website at work.
The import statement is the only code I'm executing.
Anyone who knows what causes the error?

Comment: I think this is a bug in the library itself: https://github.com/looker-open-source/sdk-codegen/issues/944

Try using a python version <3.9.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@raphael was correct. It seems like a bug introduced with Python 3.10.
It seems like the work computer had installed a new Python version automatically.

I uninstalled Python (all versions) and then installed Python 3.8
(Btw: Python 3.9 didn't work for me).

Then I reinstalled Looker-sdk via pip, and it works.